# If $H \leqslant G$, $N \trianglelefteq G$, why does $HN=NH$ imply $HN \subseteq \langle H,N \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

This is related to Geoff Robinson's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/subgroup-generated-by-two-subgroups).

Specifically, I don't understand why if $H \leqslant G$, $N \trianglelefteq G$, then $HN=NH$ implies that $HN \subseteq \langle H, N \rangle$, where $\langle H, N \rangle$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by the union of $H$ and $N$.

**Could somebody please explain that inclusion to me?** (the other inclusion, $\langle H, N \rangle \subseteq HN$ is obvious, since $\langle H, N \rangle$ is the smallest subset containing both $H$ and $N$.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always true that $HN \subseteq \langle H, N \rangle$ because $\langle H, N \rangle$ contains all products $hn$ (and more).

The hard part is $\langle H, N \rangle \subseteq HN$. For that, you only need to prove that $HN$ is a subgroup.

Comment: I already showed $HN$ was a subgroup. I just didn't understand what $HN \subseteq \langle H, N \rangle$ had to do with $HN = NH$.

Comment: @JessyCat it doesn't.

Comment: ugh. Good times.