# Given two subgroups is each one of them normal in the generated subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $A,B$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. Let $\langle A,B\rangle$ be the group generated in $G$ by $A$ and $B$. Is it true that $A$ (or $B$) is a normal subgroup of $\langle A, B\rangle$?

My guess is that this is false, so let me ask what I am really interested in, although if the following is false I can further strengthen the hypothesis:

Let $A,B$ be two $Lie$ subgroups of a $Lie$ group $G$. Let $\langle A,B\rangle$ be the $Lie$ group generated in $G$ by $A$ and $B$. Is it true that $A$ (or $B$) is a normal subgroup of $\langle A, B\rangle$?

Comment: For a counterexample in $S_3$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/subgroup-generated-by-two-subgroups?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take any simple group $G$ and any two non-trivial, proper subgroups $A,B$ that generate it. As a concrete example: take any [Tarski monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) and any $\langle g\rangle, \langle h\rangle$ for two distinct and non-trivial elements $g,h$.

The same applies to Lie groups, since you can just enforce dimension $0$ on the previous example. If you want higher dimension then just take the product with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: These are good points.