# Let $P<G$, $H<G$. What does $\langle P,H\rangle$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Let $P<G$, $H<G$. What does $\langle P,H\rangle$ mean?

I think it's the group, generated by the set of all elements of P and H, but I'm not quite sure though.

Comment: You are right. .

Comment: Another way of describing this group is 'the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $P, H$'.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/subgroup-generated-by-two-subgroups), for example.